# Weird error when using amsart + tocdepth + paragraph

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, errors, sections-paragraphs, amsart

For the following MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\title{Hi}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{B}
\paragraph{D}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \r@tocindent4 
l.11 \end{document}

?
```

and I can't really figure out why. If I change `amsart` to `article`, or remove the `\setcounter` line, the error goes away.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `amsart` doesn't support `tocdepth=4`. But also, having too deep sectioning level in the ToC looks weird. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: I actually don't want that, but I would like to be able to want it in principle. the example also gives an error for tocdepth=3. But if the answer is that it can't be made to work with amsart then I'll accept that as an answer too.

Comment: I'm editing the question to say tocdepth = 3.

Comment: Hm... From what I can see, it _should_ support `3`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `amsart` only supports `tocdepth` up to `3`, because it only defines the variables `\r@tocindentX` for −1 ≤ *X* ≤ 3.

Even then, this looks like a bug in `amsart`, when you set `tocdepth` to 3.

The class defines:

```latex
\def\l@subsubsection{\@tocline{3}{0pt}{1pc}{7pc}{}}
```

and then also does:

```latex
\let\l@paragraph\l@subsubsection
```

The first line is OK, because it defines the ToC entry for a `\subsubsection` to be at level 3 (which is supported). However the second line also defines the ToC entry for *`\paragraph`* to be 3, which causes trouble, because `\paragraph` is level 4 (it does the same for `\subparagraph`.

The correct definition would be:

```latex
\def\l@paragraph{\@tocline{4}{0pt}{1pc}{7pc}{}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@tocline{5}{0pt}{1pc}{7pc}{}}
```

If you add those lines to your document, it compiles:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
% bug fix:
\makeatletter
\def\l@paragraph{\@tocline{4}{0pt}{1pc}{7pc}{}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@tocline{5}{0pt}{1pc}{7pc}{}}
\makeatother
%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\title{Hi}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{B}
\paragraph{D}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this did solve the orignal problem, but a quick follow-up question: if I would like to set `tocdepth` to 4, how can I make sure the value `\r@tocindent4` is defined?

Comment: Adding the following to your solution does the job : `\@xp\gdef\csname r@tocindent4\endcsname{0pt}`